# Why do some bookmark icons have a red background in Firefox?

Tags: firefox-for-android, bookmarks

I have Firefox for Android installed on both my phone (Nexus 5X) and tablet (Nexus 9).

On my phone, some bookmark icons have a red background:

[image: Phone]

Whereas on my tablet they appear "normal":

[image: Tablet]

What does the red background mean? I couldn't find an explanation online. Even on Mozilla's help website the YouTube icon has a red background.

Comment: This explains it as a [site](http://johnbokma.com/firefox/rss-and-live-bookmarks.html) having RSS feed. Possible reason it doesn't appear on your tablet is configuration of browser? Try with identical browse settings as on your phone

Answer (score 0):

It's a small cosmetic feature of Firefox: [dominant color as favicon background](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=839855#c19).

To put it simply, Firefox will try to calculate the dominant color of an icon, and apply it as the background. Here is the screenshot of the feature while it's WIP (might not apply to current version).

[image: dominant color as favicon background]

<sup>Image credit to [Margaret Leibovic](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=839855#c20)</sup>

As for the reason why some of the icons have it or not, it might be probably a bug on Firefox.

---

Further reading: [Dominant Favicon Color, Revisited on Android - Margaret Leibovic](http://blog.margaretleibovic.com/2013/05/08/dominant-favicon-color-revisited-on-android.html)