# android firefox 68.0 weird background colour

Tags: firefox-for-android

The firefox browser on my Samsung tablet appears to have a pink background on the bookmark list panel and "back button" history list pane. On the history panel, there's a pink stripe under the 'recently closed and 'synced devices' section (behind where it states the number of tabs or devices, and stretches across the screen) all the other backgrounds are the default whitish colour. Anybody know what's going on and how to sort it? I couldn't find anything in config, and I have another tablet with the same version of firefox which does not have this issue.
Cheers![image]pg)[image]

Comment: Hi, could you take a screenshot and post/upload it here? Is it similar to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/131328/44325)?

Comment: Hi Andrew, updated the original post with pics :)

Comment: Is this really the latest Firefox version for your device? On my tablet Firefox shows version 89.1.1.

Comment: No, it's not the latest, Robert. But I don't like the new UI/layout of the latest versions (e.g. buttons not being as readily accessible)